# What is the difference between an @property and getters/setters for methods that "look" like properties?

Tags: ios, properties, setter, getter

I understand the key differences/process. A property creates the getters and setters for a class variable. It also (now) synthesises it with a private variable with a `_` prefix.

Great.

Now, I want some methods to act like a property. So I have a `UIView` subclass which has a `UILabel` subview.

I want to create the two methods `- (NSString *)text` and `setText:(NSString *)text` in order to set and get the text of the UILabel.

Obviously this is ACTING like a property (you can do `[myCustomElement text]` and `[myCustomElement setText:@"whatever"]`) so I *feel* like I should define a property, but what use would this have, if any?

My getters and setters will look like this:

```
- (NSString *)text {
    return self.textLabel.text;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    self.textLabel.text = text;
}
```

Comment: So what is your Question ?

Comment: One difference is that properties on classes can be introspected ( `class_copyPropertyList`, `class_getProperty`, `protocol_copyPropertyList`, `protocol_getProperty`, `property_getName`, `property_getAttributes`) in a way which manually implemented setters and getters can not.  Of course, both property setters/getters and manually implemented setters/getters can still be introspected via `class_copyMethodList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this, but I would discourage you from doing so. To have methods that look like standard accessor methods (getters and setters), but are really updating UI controls is only going to be a source of confusion in the future. This only undermines your code's readability when methods are performing functions that don't conform to conventional practices. Plus you already have a property for your `textLabel`, so these methods don't buy you very much.

By the way, the standard auto-generated accessor methods provide other useful functions (doing the necessary memory management on the basis of the qualifiers you specify when you define the property, enabling [key value observation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) for some future date where you might need such functionality, etc.), so I would be reticent to replace them with your own methods unless you are expert in these concepts.

If you're doing stuff different than the standard accessor methods, I'd suggest using method names that are less likely to be a source of confusion in the future.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. I wanted to make it as much like a standard UILabel as possible, so `setText` and `text` would be useful functions. But I guess that in essence you're right I should not try to make it look like a property when its really not. :)

Answer (score 1):

text is already a property (called *text*) of *yourCustomElement* property *textLabel* ( that's why you access it using dot notation *yourCustomElement.textLabel.text*)

in this example the getters/setters for the text property should/can only be inside the textLabel Class

Those two methods are just convenience methods to set/get a property of a property (fine, but they're not getters/setters and shouldn't look them)

Answer (score 1):

I think for your specific example, it's fine not to define a property.

Properties (as far as I can work out) provide handy shorthands that ensure proper retain/releasing (when appropriate) under the hood.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/08/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

Answer (score 1):

> what use would this have, if any?

There are many **Uses** :

**1)** You can use properties to do some Calculations , Updating Object's State , or some Caching like stuff.

**2)** Have you heard about **Key-Value Coding (KVC)** and **Key-Value Observing (KVO)** in Cocoa ? They are depended on Properties. Check : [KVC Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) and [KVO Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i).

**3)** Using properties you could put some memory management code in the accessors.

Comment: You found the question then? haha. Thanks for this - going based on your answer and others I don't think its right to define a property for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare it as a property, and override the getters/setters, then you have access to using dot notation to change or retrieve the value.

Ex:

```
myCustomElement.text = @"whatever";
```

Comment: You don't need to declare a property to use dot notation.  `myCustomElement.text = @"blah"` will call through to `-[CustomElement setText:]` even if no property is declared.

Answer (score -1):

long storry short:@synthesis generates getters and setters. So using synthesis saves you typing.

Your code however is not the same as `@synthesis textLabel` because your code allows only changing the labels text. @synthesis would allow changing all properties.

Here is some useful information about @synthesis / getters / setters

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html

Comment: THe link deos not show how to create getter and setter with custom content

Comment: @AlexWien he already knows how to do getters / setters (included in the question) but this link describes \@properties and \@synthesis which should help him to decide which one to use